# Get a random date within a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update my columns `dateStart` and `dateEnd`. These dates should get a random date between two dates.

So `dateStart` should have a date range from

*2014-01-01 to 2018-01-01*

and `dateEnd` should have a date range from

*dateStart to 2018-01-01*

Pseudo SQL:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET dateStart = RandomDateBetween('2014-01-01', '2018-01-01');

UPDATE myTable
SET dateEnd = RandomDateBetween(dateFrom, '2018-01-01');
```

Comment: Another possibility, not contained in the duplicate link, would be to create a calendar table covering your range, and then select one row, using `LIMIT` with a random ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dates are after 1/1/1970, you can generate a random timestamp between two timestamps using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. This works for leap years too:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-1-1') + FLOOR(
        RAND() * (
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-1-1') + 1
        )
    )
)
```

You can make it a function called `RandomDateBetween` and your queries will work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION RandomDateBetween (date_from DATE, date_to DATE) 
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN 
  DECLARE result DATETIME;
  SET result = (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) + FLOOR(
                          RAND() * (
                              UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_to) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) + 1
                          )
                      )
               ));
  RETURN DATE(result);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sorry I am very new to this, how do I have to use it? should I replace `RandomDateBetween` with that whole thing? And I replace the strings with my own dates?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or you can simply create a function in MySQL, call it `RandomDateBetween`, copy my answer to it, and replace the dates with parameters. Then your queries will work without any change. See my updated answer.

Comment: `UPDATE seminar
SET dateFrom = (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01') + FLOOR(
        RAND() * (
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01') + 1
        )
    )
));` this workd but it prints "1036 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1292 Incorrect date value: '2016-01-07 04:23:35' for column 'dateFrom' at row 1 1292"

Comment: If the `dateFrom` type is `DATE` (not `DATETIME`), you need to enclose the `SELECT` in the `DATE()` function. So `UPDATE seminar SET dateFrom = DATE(SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01') + FLOOR( RAND() * ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01') + 1 ) ) )));`